# Create anchor tags dynamically in Vue.JS

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a JS-object and I need to be able to create html elements out of it and render it in Vue.JS. My solution until now was to get the object, create the HTML-elements as strings out of it and then just add it to the template. However, although this shows the elements correctly, the anchor tags are not clickable.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <template v-if="elementData">
      <ul>
        <li v-for="(value, key) in elementData" :key="key">
          <div v-html='value'></div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </template>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
const about = [
  [
    'This is normal text ',
    {
      text: 'im a link',
      link: 'https://www.stack-overflow.com',
    },
    ', is not bad ',
  ],
  [
    'More text and text',
  ],
];

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      elementData: [],
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    this.setData();
  },
  methods: {
    setData() {
      this.elementData = about.map((paragraph) => {
        let pElement = '<p>';
        paragraph.forEach((part) => {
          if (typeof part === 'object') {
            const link = `<a target="_" :href="${ part.link }">${ part.text }</a>`;
            pElement = pElement.concat(link);
          } else pElement = pElement.concat(part);
        });
        pElement.concat('</p>');
        return pElement;
      });
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

The problem probably comes from me not creating the actual html-elements (like when using document.createElement('div') with vanilla JS). However, I don't know how to do this Vue.JS.

Comment: render function can solve your problem. take a look at it https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of manipulating the DOM manually, you can use [Vue's conditional rendering](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html) to achieve the same goal. Take a look at this solution below:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <template v-if="elementData">
      <ul>

        <li v-for="(paragraph, key) in elementData" :key="`paragraph-${key}`">
          <span v-for="(part, partKey) in paragraph" :key="`part-${partKey}`">
            
            <!-- Render an anchor tag if the part is a link -->
            <template v-if="isLink(part)"
              ><a :href="part.link">{{ part.text }}</a></template
            >
            <!-- Else, just put output the part -->
            <template v-else>{{ part }}</template>
          </span>
        </li>

      </ul>
    </template>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
const about = [
  [
    "This is normal text ",
    {
      text: "im a link",
      link: "https://www.stackoverflow.com",
    },
    ", is not bad ",
  ],
  ["More text and text"],
];

export default {
  ...
  data() {
    return {
      elementData: [],
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    this.setData();
  },
  methods: {
    isLink(e) {
      // You can change this condition if you like
      return e && typeof e === "object" && e.link && e.text; 
    },
    setData() {
      this.elementData = about;
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Notice how we just created elements based on conditions. We render an anchor tag if the part is an object, and has the link and text attribute. Else, we just display the string.

[image]

[See live demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-moon-lpi8f?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue:0-475)